# SetWindowPos causing crash in c# code

Tags: java, c#, wpf, windows, interop

I am executing the SetWindowPos method in my c# wpf client code which has java application integrated in one of the tab. Though it runs fine for other .net controls , it fails when I pass the handle of java app.

Below is the line which crashes.At the time of crash I can see the contents of the javaapp in the background on top of it is a "app not responding" dialog which comes and then my wpf application crashes eventually. The object handle gets the correct value for the window.

```
SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOP, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE );
```

I tried to use below(only change is SWP_NOSIZE) , and this time it doesn't crash but it is not showing the content of the java client window.

```
SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOP, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Anyone faced the similar issue and is there a way to fix this ?

My system is a 64bit OS and my wpf app is a bit process app.I have 64bit java installed in my system and accessbridge2_0_2 installed.

Added the crash details from my event viewer:

```
 Fault bucket 120266198386, type 4
 Event Name: APPCRASH
 Response: Not available
 Cab Id: 0
 Problem signature:
 P1: mywpfapp.exe
 P2: 1.3.0.191
 P3: 558281c8
 P4: windowsaccessbridge-64.dll
 P5: 2.0.6.0
 P6: 4dac90f0
 P7: c000041d
 P8: 00000000000082b2
 P9:
```

P10:

Comment: No errors whatsoever? Check your Event Viewer for recent application errors.